# \numexpr behavior in math mode and/or TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, programming

I am attempting to create a triangular grid of numbers like shown below:

[image]

This was created in Ti*k*Z by hard-coding each point, but I would like to generate the grid procedurally so I can make adjustments easily with a large number of points. The following code is how I have approached the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \foreach \s in {2,...,4} {
        \foreach \m in {1,...,\numexpr\s-1} {
            \def\n{\s-\m}
            \draw (\n,-\m) node {$a_{\m\n}$};
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However this produces the following undesired result:

[image]

My thought to resolve this issue was to add `\numexpr` in the `\n` definition or prior to `\n` in the nodes.  However this produces the error `you can't use '\numexpr' in math mode`.

I'm at a loss as to what to do next.  How can I evaluate variables like this in math mode in a Ti*k*Z picture?

As a further note, if I for testing purposes ignore my need for math mode and simply put `\numexpr\n` in the node text I instead receive the similar error message `you can't use '\numexpr' in restricted horizontal mode`.

Also, if possible I would like to preserve this `\foreach` iteration structure as it is ideal for other annotations I am using in my full application.

Comment: Probably `\the\numexpr\s-1\relax`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `\edef\n{\the\numexpr\s-\m}`, or just use it in the subscript:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \foreach \s in {2,...,4}{
    \foreach \m in {1,...,\numexpr\s-1}{
    \draw (\s-\m,-\m) node {$a_{\m\the\numexpr\s-\m}$};
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is already one answer how to use `\numexpr`, one how to rewrite your loop to avoid it, and here is another possibility : you can use the tools provided by `foreach` to make calculations. You can use `count` and `evaluate`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
      \foreach[count=\t from 1] \s in {2,...,4} {
          \foreach[evaluate={\n=int(\s-\m)}] \m in {1,...,\t} {
              \draw (\n,-\m) node {$a_{\m\n}$};
          }
      }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Avoid additional calculations. Try to think of another way of using nested `\foreach`s.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \foreach \y in {1,...,3} {
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\numexpr4-\y} {
      \draw (\x,-\y) node {$a_{\y\x}$};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Like I said in the post, due to the way I other annotations are drawn I would like to keep the same loop structure I used.

Comment: @PGmath Of course you can always keep the loop structure. However, that means you are making your problem unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: It's not unnecessarily complicated if I necessarily need that structure though.